# How to Cover Small Window but allow Light?

Tags: lighting, windows

I want to prevent my neighbors to see through my window but allow maximum light. Blinds are not possible there in the small one. The small window

[image]

Some transparent layer/membrane could work, not any permanent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many [films](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Artscape-24-in-x-36-in-Etched-Leaf-Decorative-Window-Film-01-0128/100616388) available to obscure glass -- frosted, patterned, etc.

[image: frosting]

They are self adhering and can be fairly easily removed. They come in a variety of sizes and can be cut to size.

Look for them in big box stores or window treatment stores.

```
 Images and links are examples only, not an endorsement of goods or sources
```

Comment: ...weird; I put exactly that pattern film on my bathroom windows...